# What or That which here?

Tags: word-choice

In this sentence

> ___ you need is a holiday.

I think I can definitely use what here, but is *that which* also possible? Why and why not?

Comment: Using ***that*** instead of ***what*** in such contexts is at the very least ***dated*** and/or ***poetic/ literary***, if not actually ***archaic***. Avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

A good test of whether you have the right word is if you can reverse the statement:

- What you need is a holiday.
- A holiday is what you need.

Both of these are idiomatic.

"That which" isn't really used that often in modern English. The classic Shakespeare quote "*that which we call a rose*" would probably be rendered as "*what we call a rose*" today. But when we do use it, it would be to point to something specific that can be identified. '*That which we call a rose*' **is** a rose. We wouldn't use it to pose a question, eg "*what do we call this?*" But you could ask "what do you need?" and the answer could be "a holiday!".